# Bitcoin wallet file location in smartphone

Tags: bitcoind, private-key, buy-bitcoins, wallet.dat, e-wallet

I would like to know where is the wallet file (or private keys) stored on usually in the Bitcoin mobile wallet such as Android wallet (Mycelium or Bitcoin wallet)? Because I installed Bitcoin wallet and I could not find where are the private keys storing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android Bitcoin Wallet application stores data using androids [MODE_PRIVATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) in the following location:

> `/data/data/de.schildbach.wallet/files/wallet-protobuf`

It is worth noting that this is not compatible with your standard wallet.dat file from bitcoin-qt but may be compatible with other bitcoinj clients that support protobuf formats.

Some actions in the app cause a backup file to be created in up to two locations.  The first is a key backup at:

> `/data/data/de.schildbach.wallet/files/key-backup-protobuf`

The second is the external backup feature which  is stored on the SD card at the following location:

> `/sdcard/Download/bitcoin-wallet-backup-<yyyy-MM-dd>`

Here is the link to detailed specs of the [Android bitcoin wallet](https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/tree/master/wallet)

Answer (score 0):

For the Bitcoin Android wallet, you can do a backup from inside the app.  The backup will be located here by default `/sdcard/Download/bitcoin-wallet-backup-<yyyy-MM-dd>`.  See the `Files` section of [this page](https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/tree/master/wallet) for more details.